# How to return a value in Recursive function with a for loop

Tags: php

I've been trying so hard to get this to work, i have a Tree which has children and its children can have also children, so i have to do recursive call to loop over all the array.
I want to add an extra 30(int) for every child this tree has, and return the value at the end, but because i am using a foreach loop i can't return as it will break the for loop, here is my code:

```
<?php 
     $ENTRY_PRICE = 100;
     $LEVELS_PROFIT = array(30,20,10,5,2.5,6,9);
         
     function RecursiveProfit($parent,$level) {
        static  $sumProfit;
        global $LEVELS_PROFIT;

        echo($parent['firstName'] ." ".  $sumProfit. " </br>" );
        if ($parent['children'] == null) return;

        foreach($parent['children'] as $child) {
            $sumProfit += $LEVELS_PROFIT[$level];
             RecursiveProfit($child,0); 
        }

       
    }
    

    
    
     function calculateUserProfit($userArray) {    
         RecursiveProfit($userArray,0);
    }


?>
```

now this code is looping through every child and its working fine but i can't return `$sumprofit` value no matter how hard i try. i tried making a global $sumprofit but its not a good practice

i am a beginner in php so bare with me.
thank you in advance.

- Tried adding return , but for loop broke it.
- Tried making a global variable , and checking if its set

edit: array structure

```
$DATA_ARRAY = array([
    'id'=> 1,
    'firstName'=> "Random1",
    'lastName'=> "Random2",
    'level'=> 0,
        'children'=> 
            
                    array([
                    'id'=> 2,
                    'firstName'=> "Random3",
                    'lastName'=> "Random4",
                    'level'=> 0,
                                'children'=> array([
                                    'id'=> 3,
                                    'firstName'=> "Random5",
                                    'lastName'=> "Random6",
                                    'level'=> 0,
                                    'children'=> null
                                ],[
                                    'id'=> 4,
                                    'firstName'=> "Random7",
                                    'lastName'=> "Random8",
                                    'level'=> 0,
                                    'children'=> null
                                    ])
                        ],
        
                    [
                    'id'=> 5,
                    'firstName'=> "Random12",
                    'lastName'=> "Random13",
                    'level'=> 0,
                    'children'=> null
                    ]) 
    
            ])
```

Comment: How about returning _after_ the loop?

Comment: First problem, `$level` is always 0.

Comment: @ADyson it wouldn't work, i tried adding a count and checking if its equal to arraysize but it will not work, as im not returning any value inside the foreach loop also

Comment: Instead of returning inside the loop can you add the property and bind it to the child? At the end of the loop, you will have that property in every child.

Comment: What is your `userArray` structure? Can you provide that?

Comment: @NehaSoni done, i edited the post above

Comment: @NehaSoni the userArray is DATA_ARRAY[0]